# How to use stack() function correctly to extract marginal means of ANCOVA in R?

Tags: r, lapply, ancova

I'm a beginner of R, and I would like to extract marginal means from ANCOVA tests performed on over 200 outcome variables. It worked well when I only used `stack()` on only one outcome variable, but I got error when I use both `stack()` and `lapply()`.

Here I use the built-in dataset "iris" to display the problem.
The dataset "iris" has three levels at Species, and I use `Petal.Width` as covariate, `Species` as predictive variable, and the first three columns of variables as outcome variable.

**My purpose is to extract multiple marginal means of the corresponding outcome variables at the same time rather than perform extraction one by one.**

```
#load data and packages
data("iris")
library(car); library(compute.es); library(effects); library(ggplot2);
library(multcomp); library(pastecs); library(WRS)

#set contrasts for the following ANCOVA tests
contrasts(iris$Species) <- contr.poly(3)

#perform 
list2 <- lapply(colnames(iris)[1:3], function(x){
anova_fit = aov(reformulate(c("Petal.Width","Species"),x), data = iris)
summary(effect("Species",anova_fit, se=TRUE))
})
```

The above code worked well with the help of @StupidWolf after I raised the former question ([How to extract marginal means of multiple variables with effect() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624192/how-to-extract-marginal-means-of-multiple-variables-with-effect-function)). **And then I got error when I perform the following code:**

```
means.all <- stack(lapply(colnames(iris)[1:3], function(x){
anova_fit = aov(reformulate(c("Petal.Width","Species"),x), data = iris)
summary(effect("Species",anova_fit, se=TRUE))[[5]][1]
}))[2:1]
```

**The error is** `Error in rep.int(factor(names(x), unique(names(x))), lengths(x)) : invalid 'times' value`.

But when I extract marginal mean on only one outcome variable (take `Sepal.Length` as an example), I could extract the marginal mean with the code below:

```
anova_fit = aov(reformulate(c("Petal.Width","Species"),"Sepal.Length"), data = iris)
means1 <- summary(effect("Species",anova_fit, se=TRUE))[[5]][1]
```

I do not know how to correctly use both the `stack()` and `lapply()` to extract marginal means.

Many thanks!

Ella

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you want your final expected output to look like.

Probably, you can try this approach :

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list2, function(x) 
  data.frame(prop = c('effect', 'lower', 'upper'), 
            rbind(x$effect, x$lower, x$upper))))


#    prop setosa versicolor virginica
#1 effect   5.88       5.82      5.83
#2  lower   5.49       5.68      5.49
#3  upper   6.27       5.96      6.17
#4 effect   4.17       2.67      2.33
#5  lower   3.93       2.58      2.11
#6  upper   4.42       2.76      2.54
#7 effect   2.43       4.13      4.71
#8  lower   2.13       4.02      4.44
#9  upper   2.74       4.24      4.98
```

---

You can also simplify this by replacing `do.call` + `rbind` with `purrr`'s `map_df` :

```
purrr::map_df(list2, function(x) data.frame(prop = c('effect', 'lower', 'upper'), 
                                 rbind(x$effect, x$lower, x$upper)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! It's very similar to what I want. @Ronak Shah